# Groovy JasperReport Missing method exception with the possible solution being listed as the method I call

Tags: java, groovy

So, the method exists. It tells me the method exists. But when I call the method with the argument it wants, I get an error..

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: static net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdf() 
is applicable for argument types:

(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint) 

values: [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint@1effe1]

Possible solutions: exportToPdf(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint)
```

I'm missing something easy, surely

```
 //custom class
 def normalized = new NormalizedData(instance);
 def json = normalized as JSON;
 def fileName = "SLDATA_${instance.id}.pdf";
 String reportPath = confHolder.config.jasper.dir.reports + "/main.jasper"

 InputStream byteIn = new byteArrayInputStream(json.toString().getBytes())
 JsonDataSource reportJSON = new JsonDataSource(byteIn)

 JasperPrint report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, [:], reportJSON)

 FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(
    new File("${conf.outputDir}/${fileName}"),
    JasperExportManager.exportToPdf(report)
 )
```

Comment: You missed the `static`. Apparently you're not associating the method call with an appropriate instance.

Comment: bingo. exportToPdf is not static, exportReportToPDf is. Staring at the screen to long.

Comment: This isn't a bad question if properly fleshed out, and I'll be happy to write out a proper answer if you'll include the code snippet that gave rise to this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully, you'll see `static` in the signature provided in the error message; the suggested solution is a non-static method that requires an instance as a receiver. Using `@TypeChecked` or `@CompileStatic` when practical will help prevent errors like this.

In this specific instance, `JasperExportManager` has some static and some non-static versions of its methods. The fix is to change

```
   JasperExportManager.exportToPdf(report)
```

to

```
   JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(report)
```